# Encode and Decode String Java

Tags: java, android, string, encode

I have this code where I am trying to encode and decode and string in java, but am getting compile errors, here is the code with the errors commented in the code:

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText, SecretKey secretKey)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] plainTextByte = plainText.getBytes();
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(plainTextByte);
    Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder(); //ERROR "cannot resolve method"
    String encryptedText = encoder.encodeToString(encryptedByte);
    return encryptedText;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, SecretKey secretKey)
        throws Exception {
    Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder(); //ERROR "cannot resolve method"
    byte[] encryptedTextByte = (byte[]) decoder.decode(encryptedText);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] decryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextByte);
    String decryptedText = new String(decryptedByte);
    return decryptedText;
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Do you have imported Base64 class?

Comment: Please use `getBytes("UTF-8")` should this app at some time run on a non-UTF-8 platform, like Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports and make sure you're importing:

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Base64.Decoder;
import java.util.Base64.Encoder;
```

My IDE found what looks like a couple dozen classes named `Base64`, so it's entirely possible you're importing the wrong class even though the name matches.

Also note that the [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class was added in java 1.8, so if you're on an older version it won't be available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
...
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(byteToEncode);
```

and for decode

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64String);
```